# ML method for large list of features

Tags: machine-learning

I have a long list of access logs, associated with some persons, lets say web access-log. I want to build prediction model for some target varaible, associated with persons, and i have a training set for this.

What troubles me, is that to prepare training set, containing some extraction from web logs, like domain name + number of pages visited, i need to build some flat table with enormous number of columns, representing unique domains (10k or maybe 100k depending on part of the log i will extract).

What is a common approach for such problem? Should i try to reduce dimentionality first, trying co group up domain names? But that will be a loss of data, because i believe some combination of domains can influence target variable. Or should i learn some algorithms, able to work with "longitudal" data, because most techniques i familiar with require data to be flat?

Thanks for any advice and direction, my primary instruments are R and SQL

Comment: random sample features, such as [random forest](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm) is a good start.

Comment: But to start random forest i need to provide flat table with features, right?)

Comment: some trick here feature hashing. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#feature-hashing

Comment: I have a log to transform, lets say 3-5 millions of records, which, transfromed will get me 100k columns (my estimate) and like 100k rows

Comment: If I am doing this, I will sample first. Then investigate the benefit of adding rows and columns. In many cases, double the data(rows) have little benefit. (I am talking about if you have a "high bias model")

Answer (score 0):

Loss of data isn't all bad in statistics. Consider the simple average: useful in many instances because it throws a lot of the data *away*. Anyhow, if I'm not mistaken, using PCA might well be a very effective solution in this situation. Give it a shot.

Comment: But to do PCA i have to do the job of making large flat table first, right?

Comment: The way you're describing things, I would think so.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of approaches you can test:

1. Hypothesis based features: if you have a list of errors which you know are linked to response variable you will create features
2. Frequency based features: If you are building ML model very low occurring features might not be impact if response variable is not associated to it.
3. I am not a fan of PCA analysis but I generally use regularised regression algorithm like lasso to reduce the dimension. If the numbers of variables is too much to handle I would do a uni-variant gini/ uni-variant analysis and reduce the variable set.

Hope it helps. Happy learning!!